# Correct way to check value tuples for equality in C#?

Tags: c#, tuples, comparison, equality, c#-7.0

Given two variables of type `(int, int)`, how do I check if they represent equal values?

For example:

```
var a = (1, 2);
var b = (1, 2);

var c = a == b; // Error CS0019 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands
                // of type '(int, int)' and '(int, int)'
```

How is this comparison meant to be done in C# 7? Should I use `.Equals` instead or do it some other way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Prior to C# 7.3, you had two choices: use `.Equals`, or you can write out the `==` comparison long-hand, for elements that themselves support `==`:

```
(a, b).Equals((c, d)) // true if a.Equals(c) && b.Equals(d)

a == c && b == d // works if the types support ==
```

([For details of how `Equals()` works, check out the source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ValueTuple/src/System/ValueTuple/ValueTuple.cs).)

As of C# 7.3, direct support for `==` has been added to value tuples:

```
(a, b) == (c, d) // compiler converts to a == c && b == d
```

Note that `==` here is not an operator defined by the tuple types. It's a "compiler trick" that recursively (for nested tuples) performs `==` on each of the elements. As a result, this technique can only be used if the elements support `==` themselves. As a result, this approach does not work for generics, unless constrained to types that do support `==`. So the following code will not compile:

```
public bool Compare<T1, T2>((T1 a, T2 b) x, (T1 a, T2 b) y) => x == y
```

Comment: Note that if a is Nullable<T> and c is T then even if a.Equals(c) and b.Equals(d), (a, b).Equals((c, d)) still returns false.