# Unexpected Tuple inequality

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

I am using .net core 3.1 / C# 8.0.  I have two tuples where I expect to have equal values, however the runtime returns inequality.  What is wrong with my expectation?

```c
Tuple<decimal, double> firstTuple;
Tuple<decimal, double> secondTuple;
```

Testing with:

```c
bool tuplesEqualInValue = (firstTuple == secondTuple);
```

The screenshot shows that the values of `firstTuple` and `secondTuple` hold the same values for each item.  Yet the first test returns `false`.

[image]

Documentation and other SO posts imply to me that the test should return `true`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.3/tuple-equality

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44194321/10340388

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5069777/10340388

Comment: Just tested `bool secondTestTuplesEqualInValue = firstTuple.Equals(secondTuple);` and it returns `true`.

Comment: Just looked into Tuple.cs and did not found any introduced operator, and I really don't understand why Microsoft is stating that it supports `==` operator for tuple value equality.

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev Tuple types specifically refer to `ValueTuple`, which *do* have that override

Comment: Charlieface, Thanks, now it makes sense for me.

Comment: Seems to be right though: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0BJTYj

Comment: In short ValueTuples have the expected behaviour, and ***is*** the new hotness

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first two of your links talks about [`System.ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=net-5.0), which is not what you are using here ([`System.Tuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2?view=net-5.0)), so they are rather irrelevant for this question. Though, if you are using a C# version that supports them, consider switching over to using `ValueTuple` instead. [Here's a start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples).

The third link talks about the equality of `System.Tuple` using `.Equals`, but you are using `==`. If you had used [`.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2.equals?view=net-5.0#System_Tuple_2_Equals_System_Object_) to compare them, you would see that they are indeed equal:

```
var firstTuple = Tuple.Create(217930.7650m, 670.556);
var secondTuple = Tuple.Create(217930.7650m, 670.556);
Console.WriteLine(firstTuple.Equals(secondTuple)); // True
```

Using `==` doesn't work because unlike, say, `string`, `System.Tuple` doesn't overload the `==` operator, so the default behaviour of comparing the references is used. ([`string` overloads `==`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.op_equality?view=net-5.0#System_String_op_Equality_System_String_System_String_))

Comment: Thanks, now that I know `Tuple` is a reference type it makes perfect sense for it to return `false`.  What's frustrating is that the MS document doesn't make it obvious it is referring to `ValueTuple` instead of `Tuple`...

Comment: @Superman.Lopez [Yes it does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuples-vs-systemtuple), the page you linked is not actually documentation, it is a proposal by the team

Comment: Indeed, I noticed it only now.  It was 1 of the first results in my search.  I was not careful enough.